# Java Socket - How to send and receive information between 3 points?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

In my application, multiple PCs will connect to the server. The server will receive the message then send to a system. The system may send a message back to the server, and this message should be sent to a PC by the server. Basically it's like this:

PC 0 --------------------> Server ----> Send PC msg to system.
System ------> Send msg to PC 0 Server ----> PC 0

The same with PC 1, 2, 3 etc...

But how can I do this? I can already get PC msg to Server and Server to System, like this:

**This is running from the ServerThread:**

```
try {

    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    if (socket != null) {

        clientList.add(new ClientThread(socket));
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {

    System.out.println(DEBUG
            + ": Failed creating client socket / "
            + ex.getMessage());
}
```

But how can I know if the incoming socket is meant to send a message to the Server or the socket should send a message to the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is called a [**`proxy`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). In order to distinguish between *clients* (PCs in your question) and *servers* (systems) you need to keep connections that were *accepted* from clients, and connections *initiated* by you to servers separate, but cross-referenced (the easiest is one-to-one mapping). Get a message on the client connection, optionally transform/filter, send on corresponding server connection, and the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically implementing instant messaging, where your system is simply another endpoint (along with PC0 ...).  Why not use something like [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/) if your server is simply being used as a message router.

You can use [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) for a client solution and any off the shelf [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) server will easily suit your needs.  If you need to customize the server you can choose one of the Java based ones like [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp).